# Remote desktop like scrollbars

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

How does the remote desktop scrollbar work .
basically if the resolution of the client is less than the machine its connecting to via remote desktop , then scroll bars are provided. Using the scroll bars , shifts the position of viewable remote desktop machine.

In this case , is the window position of remote windows handle moved ? what property is used to associate scroll bar to viewable area ?

Do we get handle to remotedesktopwindo and call set window pos on it ?  Need info for c++..
Is set setdisplay size / setwindowpos ???

Thanks

Comment: No, the remote windows DON'T MOVE.  The view ONTO the remote windows moves.

Answer (score 2):

The scrollbars exist in the *local* RDP client. The running applications aren't aware of them.

Keep in mind that you still need to follow the usual Windows rules: don't assume the top left corner is `(0,0)`, for instance.

Comment: Yes, I agree scroll bars exist in local rdp client. so with each scroll move , we move the frame or the remote controls location ? What winapi is used ? Need more info on this.  Thanks.

Comment: @user476566 The scroll bars move the frame, using the usual Windows APIs.